# Magento2 - More than 80 product cant able to import

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.3.3, magento2.3.0

I have total `1280` proudcts in my `csv` file in my `csv` only `qty` and `sku` column is there and I try with that in my live server at a time `80` products are imported successfully but more than `80` products is gives the `504 timeout error`

Can anyone suggest me the solution?

I have set the all possible solution in `php.ini` file :

```
max_execution_time = 350000
max_input_time = -1
max_input_vars = 50000
memory_limit = -1
post_max_size = 4800M
upload_max_filesize = 3800M
```

If any one know the solution for this or any other setting from server side then please let me know.

Is there no any `CDN` server.direct hosting of project.

Comment: nginx or apache?

Comment: apache and server has 6gb ram also

Comment: you need to edit .htaccess and increase memory_limit, by default it is 756M

Comment: i already set to -1 so it will take as many as bytes is that so ?

Comment: if i fluch the magento cache and cache storage from admin then it will allow to import a 90 record at a time more than that will throw a 504 time out

Comment: what errors are you facing?

Comment: i am facing the error 504 when i am try to import even 100 product from csv.please the php.ini configuration which i mention in my question